# Bridge Laptop's Ethernet to Wireless

Tags: 11.04, networking, wireless, ethernet, network-bridge

The laptop wirelessly connects to my router, while the desktop is connected to the laptop with an ethernet wire.

The desktop successfully can use the internet if I set the connection to be shared on the laptop.

The problem is, I need the laptop to forward the desktop's packets across the link unmodified, so the desktop is on the same network as the router.

The desktop needs its IP assigned by the router, so that I can access it from another computer as "192.168.1.8".

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add something like this to your `/etc/networking/interfaces` file:

```
auto br0                   #Creates the bridge
iface br0 inet dhcp        #Tells bridge to do dhcp
bridge_ports wlanX ethY    #Ties bridge between two ports
```

You'll need to find the correct `X` and `Y` by using `ifconfig` and `iwconfig`.

[source](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/howto-bridge-wireless-and-wired-network-interfaces-369455/)